# MediaWiki VisualEditor: Access auto generated paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, visual-editor

I'm working on extending an *MediaWiki* implementation with *VisualEditor* and have the following situation:

I have a div whose content (the text between opening and closing the tag) shall be different as seen in the wiki and in the VisualEditor. In the wiki, I want to see the full text, but in VE I want to see only abbreviations. Those can also be modified/deleted/extended in VE.

For example, I want to see `Product A, Product B and Product C` in the wiki, but `pa,pb,pc` in the VE. When I change that values in the VE to, let's say, `px,py` I want to see `Product X and Product Y` in the wiki.

The problem is that VE automatically creates a *Paragraph* for the text, so inside VE the data is stored like this:

```
data[i]:   My-Custom-Div-Data-Structure
data[i+1]: Paragraph
data[i+2]: T
data[i+3]: e
data[i+4]: x
data[i+5]: t
data[i+6]: /Paragraph
data[i+7]: /My-Custom-Div-Data-Structure
```

In one direction (HTML Dom -> VE Linear Data) I solved this by setting the new values to the domElement in the toDataElement-function of my custom data structure.

But how can I realize that into the other direction? I have a VE Linear Data element, but I can't set the right value as inner/outer-HTML/Text or textContent because after my custom data structure get's processed, the old values are taken from the paragraph and inserted between the divs, resulting in double text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to access the paragraph so I used a pretty ugly hack. In `ve.dm.Converter.js.prototype.getDomSubtreeFromData`, in the line where the text from the paragraph gets inserted, I added an check if the parent is of my custom data type to the `text.length > 0` check (around line 1220).

That's a terribly ugly solution but sadly I don't know of a better now.